# Ratio of aggregated values

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have data of devices and its latitudes, longitudes all stored as varchar in PostgreSQL.
When my device isn't able to latch on to the GPS - the lat, long is stored in the table as '-1.0', '-1.0'.
Here is how the table looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to calculate on per day basis, the GPS availability percentage. Which is, the ratio the number of times device had GPS (the lat, long was not -1.0, -1.0) to the total number of GPS pings sent throughout the day.

I made some effort on this:

If want to know on daily basis, how many times each device had GPS (lat, long were not -1.0, -1.0). This is the query:

```
select device_id, count(device_id) as valid_gps, date(created_at) 
from device_pings where lat != '-1.0' and long != '-1.0' 
group by 1, 3 
order by 3 desc;
```

This is the result:
[image]

If I want to know the total GPS pings for the day, the query is same as above just the where condition is not there:

```
select device_id, count(device_id) as total_gps_pings, date(created_at) 
from device_pings 
group by 1, 3 
order by 3 desc;
```

The result that I need is per day per device count of records where lat, long != -1.0 (Lets call this A)/ total records for the day for that device (Lets call this B). The problem is both A & B are aggregates. So I tried using inner join:

```
select a.device_id, count(a.device_id) as total_records, date(a.created_at) as dt, count(ll.success_records) as success_records, count(ll.success_records)/count(a.device_id) as ratio
from device_pings a
inner join
     (select b.device_id, count(b.device_id) as success_records, date(b.created_at) as dt
         from device_pings b
         where lat != '-1.0' and long != '-1.0'
         group by 1, 3
         ) as ll
on a.device_id = ll.device_id and date(a.created_at) = date(ll.dt)
```

This looks like this:
[image]

However, this isn't giving me the correct output (ratio is always 1, should not be). Can someone please point out whats wrong in my query or suggest a correct or better way to do this?

I have made a [dbfiddle for this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wwgGngBQcrFmfwc2GuS7yo/4#&togetherjs=MpJKzOH7dd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this a few different ways e.g. subquery, cte etc. Here is a cte example:

```sql
with cte as (
select device_id, 
    sum(case when lat != '-1.0' and long != '-1.0' then 1 else 0 end) as valid_gps,
    count(device_id) as total_gps_pings,
    date(created_at)
from device_pings
group by 1, 4
order by 4 desc)

select device_id,
    valid_gps,
    total_gps_pings,
    valid_gps*100.00/(valid_gps + total_gps_pings) as ratio,
    date
from cte
order by 5 desc
```

same solution as subquery:

```sql
select device_id,
    valid_gps,
    total_gps_pings,
    valid_gps*100.00/(valid_gps + total_gps_pings) as ratio,
    date
from (
  select device_id, 
      sum(case when lat != '-1.0' and long != '-1.0' then 1 else 0 end) as valid_gps,
      count(device_id) as total_gps_pings,
      date(created_at)
  from device_pings
  group by 1, 4) a
order by 5 desc
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very elegant solution. Do you please mind pointing me to a documentation/ example for subquery that solves a similar problem?

Comment: In order to make it a subquery you need to replace selecting from the cte to selecting directly from the query, see my edit above hopefully it makes sense. Always make sure to alias the subquery though or it will fail.